# How to store a string which has multiple quotes in a database

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to store a ciphertext in an Oracle database, but I am getting an error:

> identifier is too long.

Its probably because there are multiple quotes in the string. So, how do I store such a string?

For example, my ciphertext may look like:

```
b't\xb2\xb2\xd6\xab\xab[\x8d\xcc\xab\x1dK\xf7\xa4\xf5\x9a\xe5\xc7\xd2\x874\xbf\xb3\xd5\xf0\xc7\xcbL\xb1\x88\xd2\xae\xeeR\xe6\xd9f\xfc\x89\xfb\xc7\xeb\x0e\xca\xbe\x88\x1e\xa8\xcb\x12\x7f\xeaL\xe5o\x01\x0c\x9f\xd1\xfc\xc2Xe\xd9H6\xa4\x02\xde\xa8\xbb\x04\xf6\xa2\x81\xe8\xa4T\x17\xe5\x94\x1a\xd1\xf3\xca\xe8\xc4v\xb2\x94\xe0,\xb8v\x9c\x13m>W6\x1cL\x87\xde\xce-h\xcd"\xa66\xac&\x9b\xc4C\x9eK\x1fL\xff\nW\x06\x06\xc1\xe3\x7f\x1c{\xff\x93\xdb\t\xdb\x13&\x81\x0c\x06\xf1\x81\x99f\n\x7f\x99\x1e\xbd\xd4\x17\xe9\x05\xb7\x97\xf6\x1f\xd5\xb3\xffK/#6A\t\xa2\xba+\xfaxO\xb9\xa7\x86\xac\x10V\xc6\xe0\x96OfF\x9f\xaaM\xe3\xc9\xf6UNO\x15\x8e\r\x00\x07J)lZ\[]N\x181\xa3\xd4\'\x8a\x91\x81\x0c\xe4:\x88\xf8\xbe\xcc\xcc\xa18\xe2.o\xe5\xb4\xd9\xd3Fk\xf9\xff\x9a\xc8\x04\xaa\x9a\xff\xc2q&\xa7\xd2O\x8eh\xd7\xa9\x02\xc5V'
```

As you can see there is a single and a double quote in this.
So, how do I store such a string?

Comment: Parameterized queries/prepared statements. Then quotes no longer matter.

Comment: Also, what is the definition for the column?

Comment: identifier is too long just means that there is more bytes than the column can store, it should not matter if there are quotes. To work with text that has quotes, check the "q quote syntax"

Comment: You seem to be hex escaping some (non-printable ?) characters / bytes but leaving the printable charactes. Why not have all the characters in hex form, then you wouldn't need the \x notation and wouldn't need to worry about quotation, or other, characters.

Comment: @GaryMyers From comments on answers, it appears to be a python byte string being passed to Oracle (rather than an Oracle string literal) and the OP is attempting to formulate an SQL statement using string concatenation in Python with the CX Oracle package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how do I store such a string?

You appear to have binary data and not a "string"; so store it in a data type for binary data such as `BLOB`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE your_table (
  ciphertext BLOB
);
```

Then when you insert it use a parameterised query and bind variables from whatever interface you are using to access the database (from the look of your data, I would guess it is a `bytes` data type in Python):

For a positional bind variable, you can use the syntax:

```sql
INSERT INTO your_table ( ciphertext ) VALUES ( ? );
```

For a named bind variable, you can use the syntax:

```sql
INSERT INTO your_table ( ciphertext ) VALUES ( :your_value );
```

Then, when you construct your prepared statement to insert the value, you can pass your data in as the bind variable and you do not need to worry about any quotes.

Comment: I am still getting the same error:                                                                                       cur.execute("insert into rough ( ciphertext ) values(:'{}')".format(ciphertext))
cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-00972: identifier is too long

Comment: @AbdusSamee You are doing it wrong. Please [read the documentation for CX Oracle on bind variables](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html). Something like: `cur.execute( "insert into rough ( ciphertext ) values ( :variable )", variable=ciphertext  )`

Comment: And do not use string concatenation to add data into SQL statements as that is how you can introduce SQL injection attacks into your code.

Comment: Thank you very much. Will you please also tell me how to retrieve the same data??

Comment: @AbdusSamee Please refer to the documentation for CX Oracle that I linked to on the previous comment. There is an entire section on "Using CLOB and BLOB data" complete with examples.

Answer (score 1):

A simple option is to use the q-quoting mechanism, where you choose *something* (like a square bracket, curly bracket, ...) that doesn't exist in your string to *enclose* those values that have multiple single quotes. Otherwise you would have to *escape* them using double single quotes, but things get tricky once there are consecutive single quotes. It's just too complicated.

So, an example:

```
SQL> create table test (col varchar2(50));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values (q'[that's a string and I'm "Little'foot"]');

1 row created.

SQL> select * From test;

COL
--------------------------------------------------
that's a string and I'm "Little'foot"

SQL>
```

Comment: After storing my ciphertext in this method, when I retrieve it from the database it is in the form of string. Before it is in 'bytes' so now the length is changing and i am not able to decrypt it.